# Simultaneous Batch and Channel slicing in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, slice

In PyTorch I have an RGB tensor `imgA` of batch size 256. I want to retain the green channel for first 128 batches and red channel for remaining 128 batches, something like below:

```
imgA[:128,2,:,:] = imgA[:128,1,:,:]
imgA[128:,2,:,:] = imgA[128:,0,:,:]
imgA = imgA[:,2,:,:].unsqueeze(1)
```

or same can be achieved like

```
imgA = torch.cat((imgA[:128,1,:,:].unsqueeze(1),imgA[128:,0,:,:].unsqueeze(1)),dim=0)
```

but as I have multiple such images like imgA, imgB, imgC, etc what is the fastest way of achieving the above goal?

Comment: what is wrong with the current `cat`-based solution?

Comment: @Shai Just wanted to know if it can be achieved using purely slicing. I am of the opinion slicing operations are faster than cat or stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slicing-based solution can be achieved using [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) and [`repeat_interleave`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.repeat_interleave.html):

```py
select = torch.tensor([1, 0], device=imgA.device)
imgA = = imgA.gather(dim=1, index=select.repeat_interleave(128, dim=0).view(256, 1, 1, 1).expand(-1, -1, *imgA.shape[-2:]))
```

---

You can also do that using matrix multiplication and [`repeat_interleave`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.repeat_interleave.html):

```py
# select c=1 for first half and c=0 for second
select = torch.tensor([[0, 1],[1, 0],[0, 0]], dtype=imgA.dtype, device=imgA.device)
imgA = torch.einsum('cb,bchw->bhw',select.repeat_interleave(128, dim=1), imgA).unsqueeze(dim=1)
```